# Angular component reloads when pressing the Chrome debug tool rotate to landscape button

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, angular-routing, chrome-debugging

Using Chrome devtools, toggling between regular and landscape view on a specific phone/tablet (not responsive),
the app reloads the component and app.component.ts (constructor and ngOnInit)

**QUESTION** -  Is this expected behavior? I wasn't noticing this before 1 day ago and it only triggers a reload when on a phone/tablet, not in the responsive view of devtools.

**FYI** - I just opened and ran another project and it's doing it as well.

Does this mean that on an actual phone/tablet the component and project will be reloaded when the user switches from vertical to landscape mode, or is this something I messed up in my project/s or Chrome???

Any help in debugging this would be appreciated

Comment: I have this same issue. First I thought some top-level DOM element was rerendered but it turns out everything works well in Firefox. This issue is happening on Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75.

Answer (score 1):

Found this post because I was having the same issue while debugging a React app on Windows Chrome 86.0.4240.75.

This appears to have been a bug in that version.  I updated to Chrome 86.0.4240.111 and the problem no longer occurs for me.  Hopefully that'll work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same issue when using Firefox dev tools?
I noticed I am facing this issue on every website once I update my Google chrome to latest version today, however this does not happen with Firefox dev tools

Comment: Hello Jovi, it is a good idea to ask these type of additional information as comment on the question as this is not a suggested answer.

Comment: I'll check in 5 minutes and let you know